# Dynamic css file not being loaded

Tags: c#, css, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-server-side

In the `head` section of the `_Host.cshtml` I have:

```
@{
    var css = "~/css/mycss.min.css";
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@css">
}
```

The above is not loading the css file. The following works fine if I do (for testing purposes):

```
@{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/mycss.min.css">
}
```

Why is the file not being loaded in the first case?

Comment: `~` would not be valid at the start of a URL when it is bound with a variable. When it is directly in the markup, it will be interpreted by aspnetcore as a special character - but this cannot happen with variable binding

Comment: How can I solve the issue?

Comment: Remove the tilde `~`

Comment: Hi Ivan-Mark Debono, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, removing the tilde `~` solves the problem.